# Groovy error in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on Docker and created a declarative pipeline from SCM. The Jenkinsfile is placed on Github and has following code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever I build the Jenkins job I get the following error

```
 Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: groovy.lang.Binding
        at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
 jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

And when I place the code from Jenkinsfile on Github directly to Jenkins, then it builds successfully. Not sure what is the issue, though the same thing had worked earlier(I have fresh installed Jenkins on Docker)

Comment: Did you install the plugins inside the containerized Jenkins?

Comment: Yes @MattSchuchard . I accessed the Jenkins from broswer and installed the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after upgrading Script Security plugin to v1.46(latest)